# How to remove specific buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I am a bit new to coding so bear with me if I don't understand some of the terms that you use.

So basically I have 2 buttons which functions are to add and remove buttons. Once a button is added, the button's function is to display user's location.

Currently the buttons are removed by which button is last. How can I choose to remove specific button(s)?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
   button{
     height:100px;
     width: 80px;
     text-align: center;
     margin: 5px 4px;
   }
  #mainButtons button{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    }
    </style>


 <div id="mainButtons">
 <button onclick="addButton()">Add Contact</button>
 <button onclick="removeButton()">Remove Contact</button>
 </div>
   </br>
<div id="que"></div>

<script>
var increment = 0;
function addButton(){
  var id = 'btn' + (increment++);
  var que = $("#que");
  var el = $("<button id='"+id+"'>Click for location</button>");
  que.append(el);
  clickHandler(el);
}

function removeButton(){
  if (increment >= 0) {
    $("#btn"+(increment-1)).remove();
    increment--;
  }
}

   function clickHandler(el) {
   el.click(function() {
   getLocation(el);
  });
}

function getLocation(el) {
  el.html("Loading....");
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) { showPosition(el, position); });
  } else { 
    el.html("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  }
}

function showPosition(el, position) {
  el.html("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By this `$("#btn"+(increment-1)).remove();` you are already removing specific button with id `btn1/2/3...`

Comment: It was used to remove the last button and so on, if I could have a function that enables me to remove any button that I choose that would be nice

Comment: How would you target that specific button which you want to remove? by id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in multiply ways,here is what i managed to do it.

```js
var increment = 0;
function addButton(){
  var id = 'btn' + (increment++);
  var que = $("#que");
  var el = $(`<button id='${id}'>Click for location(id:${id})</button>`);
  que.append(el);
  clickHandler(el);
}

function removeButton(id){
  if (increment >= 0) {
    $(`button#${id}`).remove();
    
  }
}

   function clickHandler(el) {
   el.click(function() {
   getLocation(el);
  });
}

function getLocation(el) {
  el.html("Loading....");
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) { showPosition(el, position); });
  } else { 
    el.html("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  }
}

function showPosition(el, position) {
  el.html("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
}


document.getElementById('removeButton').addEventListener('click',function(){
  
  var input = $('#inputWithId')
  var buttonIdToDelete = input?input.val():null

  removeButton(buttonIdToDelete)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainButtons">
 <button onclick="addButton()">Add Contact</button>
 <button id="removeButton">Remove Contact</button>
 <label for="inputWithId">Button id:</label>
 <input id="inputWithId" />
 </div>
   </br>
<div id="que"></div>
```

Comment: Dude you're awesome (y) this helped a lot :D Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of removing a specific DOM element.

```
$(".btn").not(':first').remove(); // will remove all but first btn
$(".btn").not(':last').remove(); // will remove all but last btn
$(".btn").not(':last').not(':first').remove(); // will remove all in between first and last btn

$(".btn").eq(-1).remove() // will remove the last occurrence of .btn
$(".btn").eq(0).remove() // will remove the first occurrence of .btn
$(".btn").eq(1).remove() // will remove the second occurrence of .btn
```

Ah, but what I think you actually need, is simply to remove the button that is being clicked on.

You could do:

```
$(".btn").click(function (e) { 
$(e.target).remove();
}); // will remove the button that is being clicked
```

Or if the element you want to remove is not the one being clicked, but is next to the button being clicked

```
$(".btn").click(function (e) { 
$(e.target).prev().remove();
}); // will remove the closest previous element to the button being clicked
```

or

```
$(".btn").click(function (e) { 
$(e.target).next().remove();
}); // will remove the closest subsequent element to the button being clicked.
```

or

```
$(".btn").click(function (e) { 
$(e.target).next().next().remove();
}); // will remove the element after the closest subsequent element to the button being clicked.
```

And so on. Hope this helps!

Comment: I am confused haha I'm so sorry. Can you be more specific to my set of codes?

Answer (score 0):

why are you subtracting -1 after  adding button you increment will be the last button no. so you dont have to subtract it.

```
function removeButton(){
  if (increment >= 0) {
    $("#btn"+(increment)).remove();
    increment--;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know an alternative way of adding and removing specifically?

Comment: if you want to remove or add specifically then you should pass your button id in function. the other way to do is you should add both button and delete button from javascript.

Comment: you can add delete button for all button or you can set check box for all button you have added and you can delete the checked button only